# types of morphisms in Differential/Algebriac geometry

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-geometry

In differential geometry, given two manifolds, only special types of morphisms between them are, submersions/immersions/and some one or two other types of maps.

In Algebriac geometry, given two schemes, there are more than 10 types of maps between schemes that are of interest.

1. Separated
2. Quasi compact
3. Locally of finite presentation
4. Proper
5. Affine
6. Finite
7. Flat
8. Smooth
9. Unramified
10. Etale
11. Embedding
12. Closed embedding
13. fpqc morphism

and many more whose names itself far from my reach. It is difficult to even remember some names, let alone how they are defined.

Question : Why is it the case that maps between schemes are super different from that of manifolds? Or, are there analogues of above maps in differential geometry setup as well?

Comment: For what it's worth, here is a diagram for a better overview of a  bunch of types of morphisms https://www.konradvoelkel.com/wp-content/uploads/properties-of-morphisms.png

Comment: @Notone yes, I have seen that before.. thank you for reminding... :)

Comment: I don't really know if this answers your 'why', but some comments:

1) There are analogues to most of the maps in the list you gave in differential geometry: proper<->proper, finite<->quasi-finite + proper, smooth<->submersion, unramified<->unramified, etale<-> local homeomorphism, embeddings <-> embeddings etc.
2) Under reasonable geometric assumptions (say you're dealing with varieties) - you don't really have to worry about 1,2,3.

Comment: @loch it is not actually about names but about interest.. I do not remember seeing maps in differential geometry set up other than what I have mentioned before... I do not even know if I am conveying my question correctly... :)